# Promotion of Ask Ubuntu at Conferences

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, conferences

[Stack Exchange recently blogged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/) about their resolution to support attendees and speakers at conferences in the field of each Area51 Graduate. This includes us - so I would like to see what conferences in the realm of Linux and Ubuntu that it would be beneficiary for someone from Ask Ubuntu to be there and represent/promote the site?

Please provide one conference per answer, include why it would be good for someone to represent Ask Ubuntu there, average previous attendees, link to their site, and any applicable dates!

Comment: Maybe FOSScon, but you missed that by several weeks...

Comment: Would [LinuxCon 2011](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/events/linuxcon) qualify?

Comment: Abandoned question?